# Not to redirect using when clicked on submit button

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, redirect

I have code like this :

```
<form action="xxx.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ab" value="ab" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

now when i click submit button , browser get redirected to `xxx.php`.Is there any method to stop redirection and just let the script to work?

Comment: What do you understand under a redirection? You Submit the form and go to the site?

Comment: like i have a submission form i just want the script to work on clicking , but the page gets redirected towards the script page

Comment: if you don't want to form to submit, don't use a submit button.

Comment: i want the form to submit ,... but when i submit it redirects to the script page , i just want the script to work not to redirect to after working..

Comment: Then use Javascript and do an AJAX request instead. Easy to google.

Comment: -1 typing your question into google yields a lot of results including numerous stack overflow questions https://www.google.com/search?q=stopping+form+from+redirecting&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 1):

You should use ajax!
http://www.simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/
Check it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the submit of the form

```
<form action="xxx.php" onclick="doSomething(); return false;" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ab" value="ab" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Now the form will first submitted when the Javascript function "doSomething()" return true. But the besser way you use a Javsscript lib like jQuery or Prototype. How the other people said here are some helpfull plugins to do this.

Comment: i don't know javascript , give me a little idea what to write in do something ... and how it works .. thnxzz

Answer (score 0):

Implement your form using ajax.  There are a few decent jquery plugins for turning an existing form into an ajax form.  Just remember to give the user some indication that their form is being processed.

Answer (score 0):

For example. Using jQuery.

In your ajax pages.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        return postForm($(this));
    });
});
```

In your main page.

```
function postForm(obj){
    method = obj.attr('method');
    action = obj.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: action,
        data: obj.serialize(),
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            // On error...
        },
        success: function(request) {
            // On success...
        }
    })
    return false;
}
```

Comment: will this effect the extension of page , i am new to javascript ajax .. plz help .. thnxz